# Can't import jpeg file in Qt

Tags: qt, import, jpeg

My task is to implement JPEG encoder/decoder in Qt. I have to process jpeg markers (for example 0xFFC4 which is start of huffman table) and data between markers. I open my jpeg file using QFile class. While debugging the result is shown in picture bellow. As you can see the value in marker[0] is -1/255 and marker[1] is -40/216, and the if statement is never true I don't know why? The code is following:

```
try{
        char markers[2];
        char TableData[64];
        QFile *file= new QFile( "NovaSlika.jpeg");
        if(file->open(QFile::ReadOnly )){
            while(file->read((char*)markers,sizeof(markers))){

                if(markers[0]=='255' && markers[1]=='216'){//FF i C4
                    char TableLength[2];
                    char tableMetaData;
                    file->read((char*)TableLength,sizeof(TableLength));//Read table length
                    file->read((char*)tableMetaData,sizeof(tableMetaData));//Read metadata
                    file->read((char*)TableData,sizeof(TableData));//Read data
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Picture of debugging process is [here](http://pokit.org/get/?c1e5c316f7a3460f9a9880725e65818c.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful in your while condition:  [read()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qiodevice.html#read) returns

- 0 if there is no more data.
- -1 if there is an error, such as reading past the end.
- # bytes read otherwise.

You should probably do:

```
while( file->read( (char*)markers, sizeof(markers) ) == 2 )
```

And this line isn't right either:

```
markers[0]=='255' && markers[1]=='216'
```

Get rid of those single quotes.  (-Wall on gcc would have warned you on this).  It should be:

```
markers[0]==255 && markers[1]==216
```

Comment: I have changed every you said in previous post and result is the same. If statement is never true.
I thing something is getting wrong when I read byte 0xFF. Decimal value of this byte is 255 and the ASCII symbol for this value is ÿ but as you can see while debugging the symbol is not ÿ, and near 255 is -1.

Comment: Is that your first while loop iteration shown in the screenshot?  If yes, step forward once more (pointer at the "if" statement).  Then what are the marker values set to?

Comment: Yes it is first loop iteration. Marker values are as shown in [this](http://pokit.org/get/?fa4a3f9947e1773526ec3367128090f6.jpg) picture. 


Try with some hex editor make file which starts with FF byte, and try read it.
 When you read first byte, compare that byte with 255 and you will get FALSE as result, and I don't understand why?

Comment: Also I try to read all bytes from file, and print them. I used following code:
 QFile file( "NovaSlika.jpg" );
        if ( file.open(QFile::ReadOnly) ) {
            QByteArray array = file.readAll();
            file.close();
            for ( int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++ ) {
                std::cout<<(int)array.at(i)<<"\n";
            }

Result is interesting: value of the first byte is -1 (first byte is FF), value of second byte is -40 (second byte is C4). I really don't understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I found solution. Instead using char markers, i used unsigned char markers for marker declaration, and everything works fine. Thx bro for your patience, time and help.